# Send POST Data using AJAX JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to send the selected item from Bootstrap dropdown in POST to my controller, but somehow it is not being sent.

In my dropdown I fetch records from the database in `<li></li> tag`, like this:

```
 <li class="dropdown">

      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Your Sites <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ><a href="#"><?php

    foreach($sites as $site)
    {

    echo "<li class='specialLink' id='$site->site_key'>".$site->site_key."</li>";
    }?></a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
```

This is my script to send POST data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( ".specialLink" ).click(function() {
    var value = this.id; //get value for throw to controller
    alert(value);  

    $("#specialLink").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //send with post
            url: "<?php echo site_url('customer/dashboard') ?>",  
            data: "value=" + value,
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

But I don't send anything in POST data at my controller, nor do I get any error message in the console.

Comment: Are you clicking on the element that has id `#specialLink`? Doing a `.submit(function(){})` just sets the event handler it doesn't execute the function immediately

Comment: what is `#specialLink`? a form? if so.. no need to submit it.. just directly do `$.ajax(...` after your `click function`

Comment: @PatrickEvans i click on that <li> link and i want data to be passed as POST

Comment: Then just do the $.ajax call, don't put it in the event handler

Comment: is just an class of <li> tage @roullie

Comment: @PatrickEvans  i am new to ajax jquery, i dont know how i should be doing that

Comment: This "," after "value", please take it out. If you don't have another property after "data:", this is not necessary and it is a syntax error.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida took it out but did not make any difference

Comment: @Rajan I am reffering to your `$("#specialLink").submit(...`..

Comment: ` var value = this.id;` here `this` means can you explain

Comment: it gives me the item i select from dropdown@MayankVadiya in my alert it show the dropdown i selected

Comment: in think it should be $(this) @Rajan

Comment: @roullie i have not defined any form but i want the data from li tag t be submitted and sent as POST

Comment: var value = $(this).attr(id); try this @Rajan and check your url path is correct

Comment: i did this but did'not work i also checked the console of my browser but shows no error, Once i my network tab got the POST data but not in PHP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104705/discussion-between-mayank-vadiya-and-rajan).

Comment: @Rajan I didn't said it would make any difference. I just said it was wrong. It won't certainly solve your problem, but it will be one problem less.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida thanks a lot But please see if you can help

Comment: That's what I am doing. You see, when you have a problem with your code, removing all possible mistakes is important. Sometimes it is just a comma that causes a big error. This was not the case here, but it could be. Since you do not appreciate small corrections, I prefer to keep silent from now on. Good luck to you, @Rajan.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida my mistake i didnt see that and sorry if u felt bad

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not using `submit` correctly. The `submit` function binds an event handler to the `submit` javascript event. Read more at https://api.jquery.com/submit/.

You just want to do the ajax request when `$(.specialLink)` is clicked, so try:

```
 $( ".specialLink" ).click(function() {
    var value = this.id; //get value for throw to controller
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST", //send with post
      url: "<?php echo site_url('customer/dashboard') ?>",  
      data: "value=" + value, 
    });
});
```

Comment: i did this but in my profiler i dont see any POST data

Comment: This "," after "value", please take it out. If you don't have another property after "data:", this is not necessary and it is a syntax error.

Comment: @Rajan also be sure to put it after the `html` has loaded.  Or enclose it with a `$(document).ready`

Comment: @Rajan, can you clarify what you mean when you say you don't see any POST data in your profiler? Do you see a POST request, but the request has no data sent along with it?

Comment: @Sohan Codeigniter Profiler show GET AND POST DATA on browser. when i click on dropdown i dont see any data in that

Comment: @SohanJain can u plese tell me where i am wrong? my url is correct my data is also correct then why its not sent to controller

Comment: @Rajan your frontend code looks good to me. Maybe try investigating your serverside code? What happens if you just hit the URL with a POST request. E.g with `curl --data "value=VALUEHERE" http://URLHERE`. Also try a GET request: `curl http://URLHERE?value=VALUEHERE`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code instead to send your data to php file:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="postExample(); return false;">Your Link here</a>

     function postExample() {
     $.post('url', {"postfield1":"val1"}, function(resp) {
         //Do something with the AJAX response
     });
 }
```

or

```
 <a href="#" onclick="$.post('url', {"postfield1":"val1"},; return false;">Your Link here</a>
```